# Is it possible in Hibernate Search to predefined Query or conditions before the indexing process?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using MassIndexer with **@Indexed interceptor** and it works just fine I am able to filter the entities. but the problem is that I have thousands of soft-deleted records, I don't want these objects to be in the indexing process since they are not important anymore.

**so, is it possible in Hibernate Search to predefined query or conditions before the indexing process?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't do indexing with predefined HQL. Rather you can intercept the indexing process and instruct indexer whether it should index, skip or remove index for entity.

Please refer to [Conditional Indexing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-indexinginterceptor) topic in Reference Guilde.

Under your conditions: when > 95% of data is not to be indexed I would suggest the following:

1. Consider manual reindexing by running query and pushing items to index as described in [Manual index changes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#manual-index-changes)
2. Consider splitting full data table and only active data table. This is a bit of data duplication but should give you considerable performance gains when working with active records only.

Comment: I've mentioned that I'm already using the interceptor.but this is not a good solution because you still querying all records, and when you have +million obj you would notice how slow the indexing work.

Comment: I don't think that Hibernate Search is good solution if you task is to reindex millions of records. But are you going to index all of them often?

Comment: I think this is the real use case of the hibernate search, it's not often but every new release, or the most painful when u want to reindex in the development env without specifying the index limit.

Comment: I haven't dug that deep into implementation but it may turn out that Hibernate session itself may slow down things for you (based on how it used at indexing and you Hibernate setup). Otherwise if you are not expecting to have > 95% of soft deleted  records this doesn't make much difference (in my mind algorithmic complexity stays the same).

Comment: Well, here is the problem, soft-deleted and arch records are over 95% :)